# Cannot convert bool to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, boolean, nan

I have a DataFrame as the one in the image and I am trying to get the sum of the logarithmic rate of return for each column. This is done by subtracting to each value the first one of its column. As there are some NaN values I want to omit them but without deleting them so the dates of each value remains as they were at the begining.

I have tried the code

```
for x in AntCris.columns:
  for y in AntCris[x]:
    if np.isnan(y)==True:
      y=float('nan')
    else:
      y=np.log(AntCris[y,x])-np.log(AntCris[0,x])
```

And I get the error key `Cannot convert bool to numpy.ndarray`. I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223419/typeerror-cannot-convert-bool-to-numpy-ndarray-when-grouping-by-multiple-colu) but I was not able to fix it. Even when I ask for `type(AntCris[x,y])` I get the same error.
[image]

Edit:
I add my dataset and how I built the dataframe. I got many files downloaded from my sources with the data. In order to unify their indexes, I built some date sets and redefined with them all the indexes. after that I just concated all the dataframes in one. Here is the code itself:

```
def perdelta(start, end, delta):
   curr = start
   while curr < end:
       yield curr
       curr += delta

Trim20052020=[]
for result in perdelta(date(2005, 1, 1),date(2020,12,1),relativedelta(months=3)):
 Trim20052020.append(result)

Trim20072020=[]
for result in perdelta(date(2007, 1, 1),date(2020,12,1),relativedelta(months=3)):
 Trim20072020.append(result)

Men200542021=[]
for result in perdelta(date(2005, 1, 1),date(2021,4,2),relativedelta(months=1)):
 Men200542021.append(result)

Men200522021=[]
for result in perdelta(date(2005, 1, 1),date(2021,2,2),relativedelta(months=1)):
 Men200522021.append(result)

Gas_Natural=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/natural-gas-prices-historical-chart.csv').dropna()
Gas_Natural.drop(Gas_Natural.columns[1],axis=1,inplace=True)
Gas_Natural['indice']=Men200542021
Gas_Natural.set_index('indice',inplace=True)
Gas_Natural.columns=['GasNatural']

PIB=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/PIB_INE.csv',sep='\t',index_col=3, encoding='latin-1').dropna()#millones de euros
PIB=PIB.drop(columns=['Tipo de dato','Agregados macroeconómicos','Niveles y tasas'])
PIB['indice']=Trim20052020
PIB.set_index('indice',inplace=True)
PIB.columns=['PIB']


IPC=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/IPC_INE.csv',sep='\t',index_col=2, encoding='latin-1').dropna()#índice como tal sin unidades
IPC=IPC.drop(columns=['Grupos ECOICOP','Tipo de dato'])
aux=Men200522021[::-1]
IPC['indice']=aux
IPC.set_index('indice',inplace=True)
IPC.columns=['IPC']
IPC[::-1]

paro=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/paro_INE.csv',sep='\t',index_col=3, encoding='latin-1').dropna()#%
paro=paro.drop(columns=['Sexo','Comunidades y Ciudades Autónomas','Edad'])
aux=Trim20052020[::-1]
paro['indice']=aux
paro.set_index('indice',inplace=True)
paro.columns=['paro']
paro[::-1]

IPV=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/IPV_INE.csv',sep='\t',index_col=3, encoding='latin-1').dropna()#índice como tal sin unidades. Solo de 2007 en adelante
cols = [0,1,2]
IPV.drop(IPV.columns[cols],axis=1,inplace=True)
aux=Trim20072020[::-1]
IPV['indice']=aux
IPV.set_index('indice',inplace=True)
IPV.columns=['IPV']
IPV[::-1]

IBEX=pd.read_pickle('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/IBEX.pkl')
IBEX=IBEX.to_frame()
IBEX.columns=['IBEX']
IBEX.index.rename('indice', inplace=True)

SP500=pd.read_pickle('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/SP500.pkl')
SP500=SP500.to_frame()
SP500.columns=['SP500']
SP500.index.rename('indice',inplace=True)

DowJones=pd.read_pickle('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/DowJones.pkl')
DowJones=DowJones.to_frame()
DowJones.columns=['SP500']
DowJones.index.rename('indice',inplace=True)

Brent=pd.read_pickle('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/Brent.pkl')
Brent=Brent.to_frame()
Brent.columns=['Brent']
Brent.index.rename('indice', inplace=True)

Oro=pd.read_pickle('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/Oro.pkl')
Oro=Oro.to_frame()
Oro.columns=['Oro']
Oro.index.rename('indice', inplace=True)

Bonos=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/E3i/gcolab/datos/BonoEspañol10Años.csv',index_col=0, encoding='latin-1').dropna()#índice como tal sin unidades. Solo de 2007 en adelante
cols = [1,2,3,4]
Bonos.drop(Bonos.columns[cols],axis=1,inplace=True)
Bonos.index.rename('Fecha',inplace=True)
Bonos.columns=['Bonos']
Bonos.index = pd.to_datetime(Bonos.index,dayfirst=True)

Datos=pd.concat([Gas_Natural,PIB,IPC,paro,IPV,IBEX,SP500,DowJones,Brent,Oro,Bonos], axis=1)
```

Then I just took a certain period of time from the DataFrame "Datos":

```
AntCris=Datos.loc['2005-01-02':'2007-07-01']
```

Comment: It's look like related with your dataset. Can you share your dataset and your code parts that you assigned AntCris?

Comment: Sure, just added that information, my bad I missed it at the begining.

Comment: Still I don't have enough information. Let's talk and be sure where is the problem. Can you remove "else: y=np.log(AntCris[y,x])-np.log(AntCris[0,x])" part of your code and try to run? Are you still get this error?

Comment: One I hace commented those two lines from the code and now I get a new TypeError: `ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`